# Jquery code to show warning before deleting file

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to delete file using jquery to show warning message and to know which file that is needed to delete, but when i click on Orange it will display warning while other don't display the warning message or delete file when i click on them my jquery `$('#DeleteJfile').click(function()` only work in first file.

```
<ul>
<li id="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-1">Orange</li> 
<li id="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-2">Banana</li> 
<li id="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-3">Mango</li> 
<li id="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-4">You</li> 
</ul>

<div class="AreYousure-box" style="display:none;">
Are you sure you want to delete this file?
<br/>
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
<input type="hidden" id="TodeletFile"/>
<input type="submit" name="yes" value="yes">
<input type="button" id="no" value="no"></form>
</div>
```

**My jquery script**

```
 <script>
    $('#DeleteJfile').click(function(){
         var TypeOfVote = $(this).attr('data-animal-type').split("-")[1];
                alert(TypeOfVote);
                 $('.AreYousure-box').toggle();
                 $('#TodeletFile').val(TypeOfVote); 
              });
    </script>
```

Comment: The id attribute should be unique within the page, so change the id="DeleteJfile" to class="DeleteJfile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be always unique in `HTML`. Use `class` for it.

```
 <ul>
   <li class="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-1">Orange</li> 
   <li class="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-2">Banana</li> 
   <li class="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-3">Mango</li> 
   <li class="DeleteJfile" data-animal-type="delete-4">You</li> 
 </ul>
```

Then

```
 $('.DeleteJfile').click(function()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use same id `DeleteJfile` in multiple elements, Please change id to class and try again. It will work.

```
<script>
    $('.DeleteJfile').click(function(){
         var TypeOfVote = $(this).attr('data-animal-type').split("-")[1];
                alert(TypeOfVote);
                 $('.AreYousure-box').toggle();
                 $('#TodeletFile').val(TypeOfVote); 
              });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `ID` should be always unique.

Event gets binded to the first ID it meets , in your case Orange was the first DOM with this ID so the click event works for Orange only,

> Use `class` instead

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/chnt8jnt/)